# round work differents way in Azure function and Python desktop

Tags: python, azure-functions

Trying to round following vector:

`pred=[0.233157992, 0.07856474, 0.0551387779, 0.05095742]`

`pred=[round(num*100, 1) for num in pred]`

Desktop output:

`pred=[23.3, 7.9, 5.5, 5.1]`

Azure function output:

`pred=[23300000.0,79000.0,550.0,5.1]`

it might be linked to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) but I still don't understand why would azure function and local python behave in a different way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could provide the complete code, cause in my test it could work as expected. Below is my azure output.

[image]

Comment: this is full code :/ Problem happened when I was trying to round probabilities returned by data science model. But problem is still here with this small sample of code with already manually truncated values